# Angular add css to FontAwesome on hover

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I have a button, with a FontAwesome icon and some text:

```
<button md-button><i class="fa fa-cog fa-2x"></i> Configure</button>
```

With FontAwesome, we can animate any icon by adding the 'fa-spin' class to the `<i>` element.

I would like to add 'fa-spin' class to `<i>` element when `<button>` is hovered over. How do I do this with Angular 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do by using only css:

1) Add class `fa-spin-hover` to button:

```
<button md-button class="fa-spin-hover"><i class="fa fa-cog fa-2x"></i> Configure</button>
```

2) Declare `.fa-spin-hover` style

```
.fa-spin-hover:hover i.fa {
  -webkit-animation: fa-spin 2s infinite linear;
  -moz-animation: fa-spin 2s infinite linear;
  -o-animation: fa-spin 2s infinite linear;
  animation: fa-spin 2s infinite linear;
}
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/OK8qW0A3SeR4aMtWW9d6?p=preview)**

Comment: Just what I needed!

Answer (score -1):

**1. with cdn:**
you can put `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">` on your head tag

---

**2. with npm**
install fontawesome with `npm install font-awesome --save`
then create vendor.scss in app folder and wirte this code 
`$fa-font-path: '~font-awesome/fonts';

@import 'node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome';`

import this file to your module `import 'vendor.scss';`

Comment: this doesn't answer the question